# How to predict stream discharge from waterlevel with few data points

Tags: r, regression, smoothing, polynomials, non-linear-regression

I have installed water level loggers (logging each 30 min) in different streams and visited these sites to measure discharge six times during summer. The measured discharge is expected to correlate to water level and thus can the logged waterlevel be used to predict discharge at 30 min resolution.

My problem is to define a function from which the discharge can be predicted - I have tried generalized additive models (gam), non-linear regression and polynomial regression, but I can not find a function that works well for the few points (6) at each station. The function between water level and discharge differ (exponential-like or sometimes linear) between sites and depend on stream channel morphometry. I would love to hear your suggestions!

**1) Load dataframes (sorry, this one is long but it is just to copy paste/source it):**

```
dfs <- list(structure(list(date = structure(c(19158, 19171, 19185, 19208, 
                                          19227, 19254), class = "Date"), q.ls = c(352, 156, 27, 28, 55, 
                                                                                   65), wh.cm = c(48, 39, 24, 25, 30, 28), site = c("agns", "agns", 
                                                                                                                                    "agns", "agns", "agns", "agns")), row.names = c(1L, 15L, 29L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    43L, 57L, 71L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(date = structure(c(19158, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             19177, 19186, 19208, 19225, 19256), class = "Date"), q.ls = c(240, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           19, 14, 19, 83, 33), wh.cm = c(30, 15, 13, 16, 24, 19), site = c("b10", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "b10", "b10", "b10", "b10", "b10")), row.names = c(2L, 16L, 30L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               44L, 58L, 72L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(date = structure(c(19158, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        19172, 19185, 19209, 19227, 19255), class = "Date"), q.ls = c(464, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      162, 33, 44, 64, 55), wh.cm = c(48, 39, 27, 33, 35, 37), site = c("frdk", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "frdk", "frdk", "frdk", "frdk", "frdk")), row.names = c(10L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                24L, 38L, 52L, 66L, 80L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  date = structure(c(19166, 19179, 19189, 19210, 19228, 19254
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ), class = "Date"), q.ls = c(299, 150, 104, 20, 30, 21), 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  wh.cm = c(60, 57, 53, 43, 46, 44), site = c("hub", "hub", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "hub", "hub", "hub", "hub")), row.names = c(12L, 26L, 40L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          54L, 68L, 82L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(date = structure(c(19160, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   19178, 19187, 19209, 19229, 19253), class = "Date"), q.ls = c(230, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 61, 30, 28, 30, 60), wh.cm = c(26, 24, 21, 21, 22, 25), site = c("lj", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "lj", "lj", "lj", "lj", "lj")), row.names = c(13L, 27L, 41L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                55L, 69L, 83L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(date = structure(c(19158, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         19177, 19186, 19208, 19225, 19256), class = "Date"), q.ls = c(508, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       38, 18, 15, 70, 29), wh.cm = c(58, 40, 34, 35, 47, 18), site = c("vla", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "vla", "vla", "vla", "vla", "vla")), row.names = c(14L, 28L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           42L, 56L, 70L, 84L), class = "data.frame"))
```

**2) plot and view**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)

plots <- function(y){
  p <- ggplot(y,aes(wh.cm,q.ls))+geom_point(size=2,alpha=0.75)+
    ggtitle(y$site[1])
  return(p)
}

p <-  dfs %>%
  lapply(plots)

do.call(grid.arrange,p)
```

Comment: I don't see why one is bad and another is good. These all look overfitted (a four-parameter Weibull model with only six data points?). A bit of exploratory plotting with log-scale for q.ls shows straight lines are pretty good fits which means only two parameters (per line). My big problem here is we don't know your criteria that makes this "best" or why you chose that form out of all the possibilities....

Comment: Ok, so I should probably not have included the dosefit bit (edited now) since it was just experimental. So the big problem with the linear regressions here is that it often result in negative predictions of discharge (q.ls) at low water level. It is also logical that the relationship is kind of exponential since when the stream is flooded, each 1cm increase in water level has a greater impact on water volume than when the stream isn't flooded. But you are right, many of these look better when log transformed so for some stations this is for sure an option!

Comment: Is your problem then to create a predictor that a) works at just these stations, or b) at other stations also which you don't have sample data for? Because for a) you can tailor the form and the fit on a per-station basis, but with b) you need a general form that works for any stations, perhaps dependent on per-station covariates that you might have (station altitude or known station catchment area etc).

Comment: Alternative a), but I do have a bunch of other stations that I choose not to include here, all of which has 6 sample points and a water level logger. I am hoping to get a suggestion of some model that is commonly used on similar data (few points, non-linear regression) and will work on most stations. I also expect that I will have to tailor some stations for them to yield sensible output, but none of the non-linear methods within my scope of statistical competence makes sense to use here, so I don't know where to start.